# C# refused in IIS Configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

I've installed a new IIS server - let's call it `MYIIS` -  on a Windows 10 21H2 (French version) on the local network. Ordinary static HTML apps now work all right on that server even when called from another machine on the local network.

On this `MYIIS` server, I've also installed Visual Studio 2022 Community in order to be able to test or maintain VS web applications directly on that server.

I have installed a web application, let's call it `MYAPP`, on the `MYIIS` server, in the `D:\INTRANET\MYAPP` folder linked to IIS through a virtual folder. I must precise that this application was originally developed in Visual Studio 2010 and uses `aspx/ashx` files. And still VS 2022 has integrated that application automatically, because when I run it on the VS 2022 platform on `MYIIS` it works perfectly well, and I can reach data from my Oracle XE server, proving the technical links on the `MYIIS` server are working well.

But when I call that same application through the IIS server, it refuses to start because of the following error:

[Error message displayed by IIS while starting the MYAPP application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGEsZ.png)

I've tried to find the answer to that problem on the Microsoft network (MSDN, TechNet), but unfortunately, I couldn't find a single page about it. I would be grateful to anyone who could give me some help to fix this problem.

Comment: Please include errors in your question as text, not an image. And you'll need to translate the error text to English, as the main Stack Overflow site you're on is English only. You should also describe how you published the site, as the source code and the actually published output are generally different. And is it a web application project (with a .csproj file) or a website project (no .csproj file)

Comment: By default, VS2022 uses IIS Express to launch a web application. Change your project setting to use IIS and see what happens.